# ¿Cual es la mejor forma de convertir TODOS los valores de una columna de un Dataframe, en UN SOLO string?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy buscando la mejor forma de convertir TODOS los valores de una columna de un Dataframe en UNA SOLA cadena (string). Mi DataFrame de ejemplo sería tal que así:

```python3
0       0
1       0
2       1
3       0
4       1
       ..
8232    1
8233    0
8234    0
8235    0
8236    1
```

El dataframe es bastante grande así que busco una solución **sin iterar** cada elemento. He probado `df.transpose()` pero no me funciona.

lo que necesito es obtener UN SOLO string con la totalidad de los valores, para después poder encontrar secuencias de datos en ese string. Es decir, en el df del ejemplo, obtendría un string de 8237 caracteres. Quedaría algo así: `'00101...10001'`
La idea final es buscar y contar en el string resultante secuencias de datos iguales, como por ejemplo `'001001'`. Cualquier idea será bienvenida.

Comment: `df[col].astype(str)`

Comment: Hola Christian, gracias por tu comentario.

Esta instrucción convierte los valores de la columna a string, pero lo que yo quiero es obtener UN SOLO string con la totalidad de los valores, para después poder encontrar secuencias de datos en ese string.

Es decir, en el df del ejemplo, obtendría un string de 8237 caracteres.

Comment: si te ha servido?

Comment: no, no es exactamente lo que busco.

Comment: por que???.....

Comment: La instrucción que me has indicado convierte el tipo de dato de la columna, pero lo que necesito es obtener UN SOLO string con la totalidad de los valores, para después poder encontrar secuencias de datos en ese string. Es decir, en el df del ejemplo, obtendría un string de 8237 caracteres. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si es la mejor, pero se me ocurre que podrías a) convertir el tipo de columna en una cadena b) convertir luego la columna en una lista común c) hacer un clásico `join()` de python para concatenar cada elemento de la lista:

```
cadena = "".join(df.tu_columna.astype(str).to_list())
```

Comment: ¡Si! Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba.